# How can I display every 4th product with different markup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm just starting out with Ruby from a java background. I'm trying to code a particular loop but can't figure out the right syntax:

Could someone help me troubleshoot this please? I'm trying to write a loop but use different css classes to change the style of each block.

Realise this is probably easy, but help is appreciated....

```
    <%= @products.each do |product, i| %>
    <% if i % 1 %>
    <div class="items-row clearfix">
      <div class="one_fourth">
            <div class="item-thumb">
                <a href="" title=""><img src="<%= image_path "thumb.png" %>" alt="" class="thumb" width="162" height="230" /></a>
            </div>
            <p><%= product.name %></p>
            <p class="bold">$79.95 AUD</p>
            <p class="color-wrap">
                <span class="color" style="background:#ddd;"></span>
                <span class="color" style="background:#f9f9f9;"></span>
                <span class="color" style="background:green;"></span>
                <span class="color" style="background:red;"></span>
            </p>
        </div> 
    <% elsif i % 4 %>
    <div class="one_fourth last">
        <div class="item-thumb">
            <a href="#" title=""><img src="<%= image_path "thumb.png" %>" alt="" class="thumb" width="162" height="230" /></a>
        </div>
        <p><%= product.name %></p>
        <p class="bold">$79.95 AUD</p>
    </div>
    </div><!-- end row -->
    <% else %>
        <div class="one_fourth">
            <div class="item-thumb">
                <a href="#" title=""><img src="<%= image_path "thumb.png" %>" alt="" class="thumb" width="162" height="230" /></a>
            </div>
            <p>Item Name</p>
            <p class="bold">$79.95 AUD</p>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? ie what are the conditions of the ifs

Comment: What result are you expecting and what result are you getting?

Comment: :) I'm trying to write rows of 4 products with different class on the first, and wrapper around the first and fourth to break up the row....

Comment: do you really need a wrapper around groups of 4. Can you not just wrap everything in a div set to the correct width and float all the inner product containing divs to the left?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got part of the answer. Slight change of syntax to use "each_with_index" instead of just each.

Still trying to work out there's a lot of variations of when a product can be the last tile and require closing, first on row, first in set, last in a row.....

Thanks guys, I think I've answered my own question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this using [cycle](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle):

```
<% products.each_slice(4) do |slice| %>
  <div class="items-row clearfix">
    <% slice.each_with_index do |product,i| %>
      <div class="one_fourth <%= cycle("first", "second", "third", "fourth") %>">
        <%= render product %>
        <% if i != 3 %>
          <p class="color-wrap">
            <span class="color" style="background:#ddd;"></span>
            <span class="color" style="background:#f9f9f9;"></span>
            <span class="color" style="background:green;"></span>
            <span class="color" style="background:red;"></span>
          </p>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

_product.html.erb:

```
<div class="item-thumb">
  <a href="" title=""><img src="<%= image_path "thumb.png" %>" alt="" class="thumb" width="162" height="230" /></a>
</div>
<p><%= product.name %></p>
<p class="bold">$79.95 AUD</p>
```

Comment: thanks as the poster above, each row of products is wrapped, so it's a traditional nested loop...for the products, display 4 at a time...

Answer (score 1):

Rather than if/else statements and CSS markup in your views, you should probably externalize your CSS, make a few partials, and make use of [ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper#cycle](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle). For example:

```
<%= @products.each do |product| %>
  <div class="<%= cycle('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth') -%>">
    <!-- 1. let the CSS class handle display differences -->
    <!-- 2. render a partial based on #current_cycle     -->
    <%= render :partial => current_cycle %>        
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks, it helps in one part, the cycle syntax may help add class attribute, but the HTML I've got, there's still a div wrapper around each row of 4....

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the mod's are your problem. It's never going to go into the first block as n%1 will always return 0. Try your logic out using [irb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell) to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [jQuery nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)